# Launch firefox with fullscreen mode from another app in android

Tags: android, firefox

I need to open firefoxbrowser from another app with a url in android,this part i have done.
But my question is,can i send some intent extras so that firefox will open in fullscreen mode ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?